# Determining if coefficent is significant

Tags: r, regression, self-study, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I am attempting to better understand regression tables but I am having some difficulty when trying to understand coefficients and $p$-values. On the table given below from R, I am trying to understand how many asterisks would be next to the church coefficient, but I am struggling to understand how to determine that without knowing the *p*-value.

Would it be 0 because 25.996 and 24.612 are much larger than the standard error?

[image: regression table]

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your post and reinsert the image. I cannot see what you’re describing. Or, try copy-and-pasting the summary output from the R console.

Comment: Hi sorry about that, I have fixed the image issue. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to predict the number of stars? Is this about reporting the $p$-values, because you can adjust the stargazer output to allow for this?

Comment: It is from a book I am trying to learn from however, I cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: If standard errors are inside brackets, then divide a coefficient by the standard error, then resulting t-statistic can be compared to the tables connecting number of sigma (statistic) with area under the PDF, you will see p-values that should match the asterisks legend.